# I'm stuck with making substitutions

Tags: python, encryption

The program I'm making involves 3 files, the encrypted text file (words.txt), a file with 3 clues in it(clues.txt) and a solved text file(we don't need to worry about it). 
This is where I have gotten to so far:

```
print('This is the encrypted code:')
CodedFile = open('words.txt' , 'r+')
print(CodedFile.read())
CodedFile.close()
time.sleep(3)
print()
print('These are a few hints to get you started:')
HintFile = open('clues.txt' , 'r+')
print(HintFile.read())
HintFile.close()
time.sleep(2)
```

Now I have to take the 3 hints from the hint file and substitute them into the encrypted code, the three hints are A=# M=* N=%. One of the words is ALMANAC, which would be #3*#%#+ encrypted. How do I get from #3*#%#+ to A3MANA+, just using the hints section, help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what cypher is used, or at least how it works? Something like a dictionary with a mapping?

Comment: You need to _try something_ and then ask a specific question. The code you posted is equivalent to `cat words.txt clues.txt` almost.

Comment: The whole point in the program is that the user figures out what letters substitute with each symbol. So no cipher is used

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that:

```
codedFile = open("words.txt")
encryptedText = codedFile.read()
codedFile.close()

cluesFile = open("clues.txt")
cluesLines = cluesFile.readlines()
cluesFile.close()

clues = {}
for line in cluesLines:
    clues[line[2]] = line[0]

print(''.join(clues.get(c, c) for c in encryptedText))
```

`cluesFile.readlines()` reads all files and returns a list of lines: `['A=#\n', 'M=*\n', 'N=%\n']`.

`clues` is a dictionary of substitutions. It will be equal to `{'%': 'N', '#': 'A', '*': 'M'}` after `for` cycle.

The last line replaces every single character `c` from `encryptedText` with character from `clues` if there is a substitution. Method `get(key, default)` of the dictionary return value assigned to key `key` or `default` if there is no such a key.

Comment: It looks OK but for some reason ' clues[line[2]] = line[0]' is causing syntax error as the string index is out of range, why is this?

Comment: @user3033630, `index out of range` means that you try to access element, which is not in `line`. The reason can be wrong content of `clues.txt`. For example it may contain empty line at the end. If so, you can add check for emptiness to for cycle. If not helped add debug output to for cycle to know the cause of error.